# Why did Hawaii become a dependent state of USA after USA was born 300 years ago?

Tags: united-states, ancient-history

I’m asking this because, I know that Hawaii is a very ancient civilization because it has an unique language, and you can’t find anywhere on Earth except in Hawaii, and when USA was born 300 yers ago, Hawaii became dependent of USA instead of being independent like when English people came to North America and they formed USA and they won Independency.  Is it logic that Hawaii is dependent of USA? Or illogic? Because, Hawaii should be an independent nation.

Like for example, Romania, is an ancient nation. We’ve been in here( in Europe) for thousands of years and we also had our islands, but they were taken by others, we had only one left which is Island of Snakes, but later it was taken by Russia. Anyway, you know what I mean. You see? That’s how, if an island were to truly belong to you, then this you suppose to have it for many, thousands of years till the *World of Ancient*.

If Hawaii were to truly belong to USA then, USA supposed to be thousands and thousands of years old just like European countries and Asian countries, am I right? So practically, USA have taken something which doesn’t belong to them which is Hawaii.

*Why did Hawaii became dependent instead of being still independent nation of USA?*

Comment: This question would benefit from research.  Please read [help] to understand how to ask questions that will attract more answers.

Comment: If geopolitics had a sense of morality or countries could call first dibs on land and be respected, then [the world would be a simpler place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes). Having a long history helps someone make their claim, but ultimately land only belongs to a country if everyone else is either unwilling or unable to take it away.

Comment: Hawaiian language is part of the polynesian language group such as Samoan, Tongan, Maori. It's culture is similar too as are the native people.

Comment: Location, location, location. Smack in the middle of the Pacific. Ideal as coaling station. If America hadn't snapped it up, someone else would.

Answer (score 3):

Hawaii is a US state  because Hawaii is economically and geopolitically stronger and safer as part of the USA than as an independent nation.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaii#Overthrow_of_1893_%E2%80%93_Republic_of_Hawaii_(1894%E2%80%931898)) summarizes the mechanism by which HI was brought into the USA.

This question seems to be based on the assumption that

> "if an island were to truly belong to you, then this you suppose to have it for many thousands of years"

I can find no evidence supporting this hypothesis. I'm not even sure that I can find a legitimate example; off the top of my head I can't think of a single political entity that has survived for many thousands of years, which would result in all islands being free and independent states.  (which would inevitably result in the conquest of those islands in short order).